# Oracle DBMS_CLOUD_NOTIFICATION empty message body

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I'm trying to send a mail from Oracle Autonomous DB (version 19c) using DBMS_CLOUD_NOTIFICATION functionality (https://docs.oracle.com/en/learn/send-email-autonomous-database/index.html#task-4-send-messages-as-email-from-oracle-autonomous-database).

The manual is pretty straightforward. Setup:
[image]

The mail is sent just fine after setup completed, but due to unknown reason it sends a naked mail with empty body. I tried with different DB users/recipients, nut got the same result.

What could be a possible cause of the issue? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to add this as a comment so my apologies for posting it as an "answer".

I just tested it on my ADB-S instance with the exact same body and I was able to receive the email with the full content. Is there any chance you can try this on a different ADB-S instance? Just want to see if it's isolated to that one instance. Independent of that request, the next step would be to file a service request so that support can investigate further.